# I call a java function and I Have Stacktrace:] with root cause in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Goodmorning, I have a question for you. 
I'm a little bit newbie about Java and JSP and I'm learning, so please don't kill me :D

I have a similar problem in two parts of my code, in the first one:
**modificaprofilo.jsp**

```
<div id="modinfopersonali" class="div1 tabcontent">
        <% User u=(User)session.getAttribute("User");%>
        <p>Email: <input type="email" value="<%= u.getEmail()%>" disabled></p>
        <p>Nome: <input type="text" oninput="this.className = ''" value="<%=u.getFirstname() %>" ></p>
        <p>Cognome: <input type="text" oninput="this.className = ''" value="<%= u.getLastname() %>"></p>
        <p>Luogo di Nascita: <input type="text" oninput="this.className = ''" value="<%= u.getLuogodinascita() %>"></p>
        <p>Indirizzo: <input type="text" oninput="this.className = ''" value="<%= u.getIndirizzo() %>"></p>

        <button class="button" onclick="modificaInformazioni()">Modifica </button>
    </div>
```

**ModificaProfilo.java**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    String mod=request.getParameter("mod");
    Database db=Database.getDatabase();
    if(mod!=null) {
        if(mod.equals("Profilo")) {
            String login=request.getParameter("login");
            String firstname=request.getParameter("firstname");
            String lastname=request.getParameter("lastname");
            String luogodinascita=request.getParameter("luogodinascita");
            String indirizzo=request.getParameter("indirizzo");

            User u = new User((String)session.getAttribute("Email"),login, firstname, lastname, luogodinascita, indirizzo);
            try {
                if(db.modificaProfilo(u)==true) {
                    session.removeAttribute("User");
                    session.setAttribute("User",u);
                    response.getWriter().write("true");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }}  

}
```

*I Add my file java, then you(and me) can understand better *

And I receive an error at line Email, but If I comment this line, I have an error at line Nome and then others.

The same error I find in:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class=" column infouser1">
        <h3>Informazioni Personali </h3><hr>
        <p>Nome: <%=u.getFirstname()%></p>
        <p>Cognome: <%= u.getLastname() %></p>
        <p>Luogo di Nascita : <%= u.getLuogodinascita() %></p>
        <p>Indirizzo : <%=u.getIndirizzo() %></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In line Nome, Cognome...

I don't understand why, I think the problem is the function u.getEmail but I think that it is right.

**This is the error in the first case**

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Reservation] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [/modificaprofilo.jsp] at line [22]

19:     </div>
20:     <div id="modinfopersonali" class="div1 tabcontent">
21:         <% User u=(User)session.getAttribute("User");%>
22:         <p>Email: <input type="email" value="<%= u.getEmail()%>" disabled></p>
23:         <p>Nome: <input type="text" oninput="this.className = ''" value="<%=u.getFirstname() %>" ></p>
24:         <p>Cognome: <input type="text" oninput="this.className = ''" value="<%= u.getLastname() %>"></p>
25:         <p>Luogo di Nascita: <input type="text" oninput="this.className = ''" value="<%= u.getLuogodinascita() %>"></p>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.modificaprofilo_jsp._jspService(modificaprofilo_jsp.java:143)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: If you get an error, post the stacktrace

Comment: @jens thanks for the answer I update my post!

Comment: i guess `session.getAttribute("User");` returns null

Comment: @Jens maybe yes, and I could be a problem of User.java ??

Comment: You need to set the `User` object in your code, like this `session.setAttribute("User", obj).

Comment: @Kepz23 No not in `User.java` Problem is that you never set the user in the session

Comment: mmmh.. this is interesting! But now I should understand what can I change :)

Comment: @Jens in my .java ( in this case Modificaprofilo.java ) I have put HttpSession session = request.getSession();

Comment: @Jens I have edited my post! Thank you for your help

Comment: @devd I have edited my post! Thank you for your help!

Comment: you should start learning basic java, exception handling, debuggin, ... before trying to create webapps. It'll make it a lot easier to understand problems you encounter later on

Comment: @Kepz23 can you check if `mod.equals("Profilo")` if true?

Comment: mmh I update my post. How can I check it?

Comment: The `doGet` method is called from some jsp page from which you're submitting to modify the profile. In that jsp page there has to be one html input field with `name="mod"` and `value="Profilo"` , if it's not there then `mod.equals("Profilo")` will be false and the following code won't be executed.

Comment: Yes in the jsp page you should have something like this:
`<input type="hidden" name="mod" value="Profilo">`

Comment: @devd in a file modificaProfilo.js i have  $.post("ModificaProfilo",
        {
   mod: "Profilo", 
   nome: element1[1].value,
   cognome: element1[2].value,

Comment: Check in your servlet doGet method `String mod=request.getParameter("mod"); System.out.println(mod);`. I guess you know how to check the log.

Comment: it prints " null "

Comment: I had read all my code, but I can't find the error.

Comment: You can check in your browser inspector/web development tool what request you’re sending to the servlet